# jquery audio player - next function problems

Tags: jquery, audio, playlist

I need help.  Whenever the next button is pressed the player will play and display the next track properly, however, the progress bar and duration do not function properly.  also the volume raises to 100 when it should stay as previously set.

https://jsfiddle.net/independentlegends/zsbo58hc/

```
<body>
  <div id="audio_player">
    <div class="audio-info">
  <!--  <span class="artist"></span> - <span class="title"></span> -->
  </div>
  <div><a id="i-legends" target="_blank" href="http://www.independentlegends.com" class="text-center"><strong>Powered by: IndependentLegends.com</strong></a></div>

<div id="audio_controls">
  <div class="clear-fix"></div>
  <div id="audio-img">
    <img class="tapecover" src="">\
    <h2 id="playlist_status"></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="tracker">
    <span id="curduration"></span>
    <div id="progressbar">
      <span id="progress"></span>
    </div>
    <span id="duration"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="clear-fix"></div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="prev"></button>
    <button id="play"></button>
    <button id="pause"></button>
    <button id="stop"></button>
    <button id="next"></button>

    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="30" step="1">
    <button id="mutebtn"></button>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="clear-fix"></div>
<ul id="mylist" cover="http://www.i-legends.com/images/LostTape.jpg" artist="MaseratiBaby">
<li data-mixtrack="1. Big Mad" class="active">1. Big Mad</li>
<li data-mixtrack="2. 24.7">2. 24.7</li>
<li data-mixtrack="3. Robbins And Jordans">3. Robbins and Jordans</li>

</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
}
div#audio_player { 
    width: 450px; 
    height: 300px; 
    background: url(images/sdeskin.png) no-repeat; 
    border-radius: 4px
}
div#audio_controls { 
    margin-left: 66px; 
    clear: both
}
div#audio_controls > #buttons > button { 
    border: none; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    outline: none; 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
}
div#audio_controls > input { 
    outline: none; 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px; 
    border-radius: 5px
}   
#audio-img {

    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 15px 15px 0px 40px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 0px;

}

.tapecover {
    width: 15%;
    z-indez: 1;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

button#prev {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url(images/prev.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    float: left;

}

button#next {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url(images/next.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    float: left;
}

button#stop {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url(images/stop.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    float: left;
}

button#pause {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url(images/pause.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    float: left;
}
button#play {
    background: url(images/play.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: contain;
    float: left;
    border: none;

}


button#mutebtn {
    background: url(images/speaker.png) no-repeat;
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px;
    background-size: contain;
    float: right !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;


}

input#seekslider{
    width:100px;
}
input#volume{
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 13px;

}

#buttons {
    width: 260px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#tracker {

    position: relative;
    width: 260px;
}

#progressbar {
    width: 260px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

    margin-right; 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url(images/progress_bg.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;


}

#progress {

    background: url(images/progress.png) no-repeat;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;

}


#duration {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: -79px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    font-size: .7em;
    color: #09F;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#curduration {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -20px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    font-size: .7em;
    color: #09F;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


input[type='range'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background: #000;
    height:13px;
    border-bottom:#333 1px solid;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower  {
    background:#000;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-upper  {
    background:#000;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
    border:none;
    background: #000;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background: radial-gradient(#FFF, #333);
    height:11px;
    width:11px;
    border-radius:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: radial-gradient(#FFF, #333);
    height:11px;
    width:11px;
    border-radius:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background: radial-gradient(#FFF, #333);
    height:11px;
    width:11px;
    border-radius:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#mylist li {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#mylist li.active{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #666;
}

#i-legends {
    clear: both;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin-top: 210px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    float: right;           
}

#playlist_status {
    float: left;
}
.clear-fix {
    clear: both;
}
```

javascript

```
var audio, seeking=false;

// hide pause button
$('#pause').hide();

$('#duration').hide();
$('#curduration').hide();


//initialize
initAudio($('#mylist li.active'));
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateProgress, false);
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", showDuration, false);


// initializer function
function initAudio(element) {
    var song = element.attr('data-mixtrack');
    var title = element.text();
    var cover = element.parent().attr('cover');
    var artist = element.parent().attr('artist');

    var progress = document.getElementById("progress");

    var dir = "audio/"

    //playlist_index = 0;
    var ext = ".mp3";
    var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase();

    if(agent.indexOf('firefox') != -1 || agent.indexOf('opera') != -1) {
        ext = ".ogg";
    }

    //create audio object
    audio = new Audio(dir + song + ext);

    if (!audio.currentTime) {
        $('#duration').html(0.00);  
    }

    $('#playlist_status').text(title);


    //insert cover
    $('.tapecover').attr('src', cover);

    $('#mylist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
}

//play button
$('#play').click(function() {
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    $('#curduration').fadeIn(400);
    showDuration();
});

//pause button
$('#pause').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

//stop button
$('#stop').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    $('#duration').fadeOut(400);
    $('#curduration').fadeOut(400);
}); 

// next button
$('#next').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#mylist li.active').next();
    if(next.length == 0) {
        next = $('#mylist li:first-child');
    }   
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    showDuration();
});

// prev button
$('#prev').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    var prev = $('#mylist li.active').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0) {
        prev = $('#mylist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    showDuration();

}); 

// Time Duration

function showDuration() {
                    var nt = audio.currentTime * (100 / audio.duration);
                    progress.value = nt;
                    var curmins = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
                    var cursecs = Math.floor(audio.currentTime - curmins * 60);
                    var durmins = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60);
                    var dursecs = Math.floor(audio.duration - durmins * 60);
                    if(cursecs < 10) { cursecs = "0" + cursecs; }
                    if(dursecs < 10) { dursecs = "0" + dursecs; }
                    if(curmins < 10) { curmins = "0" + curmins; }
                    if(curmins < 10) { durmins = "0" + durmins; }
                    curduration.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
                    duration.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
                }

function updateProgress() {

   var value = 0;
   if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
      value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
   }
   progress.style.width = value + "%";
}

// change track

$('#mylist li').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    $('#mylist li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    initAudio($(this));
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    showDuration();
});

// volume

$('#volume').change(function() {
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 100);

});

$(document).ready (function() {
    audio.volume = $('#volume').attr('value') / 100;
});
```

I am sure its the order of my code, but i am not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be apprectiated.

thanks.

Comment: Please post your troublesome code here, links to jsFiddle alone are insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  i had my event listeners in the wrong place.